# DJANGO 2.0 Can I replace a ForeignKey and add PositiveIntegerField to store the pk only

Tags: python, django

I want to replace the user `ForeignKey` by a `PositiveIntegerField`
is it permitted?

#### models.py

from:

```
from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                              related_name='sender_%(class)s',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to:

```
from_user = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this. But you lose the functionality which you get from `ForeignKey`, like fetching related value.

If you remove `ForeignKey` you can't do things like this:

```
Model.objects.select_related('field_name')
```

If you eagerly need to use `PositiveIntegerField`, you can use it.